# How does this simple chained binding works?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am learning Monads in Haskell and I am analyzing this example (http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads):

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
```

I would like to understand what is happening in this part of the function:

```
\n -> ['a','b'] >>= \ch -> return (n,ch)
```

What I understand is that `\ch -> return (n,ch)` is being composed with `\n -> ['a','b']` as argument, but I am not sure how is this happening. I was thinking that it had the following composed function:

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> [n, \n -> ['a','b']]
```

But that doesn't seem to output the same result as doing the full expression.

**EDIT 1:**

Taking into account an answer below the full parenthesization is:

```
[1,2] >>= ( \n -> ( ['a','b'] >>= \c -> return (n,c) ) )
```

Which led me to obtain this composed function:

```
[1,2] >>= ( \n -> [(n,'a'),(n,'b')] )
```

Comment: Be careful with the term "partial evaluation". It's a technical term that's unrelated to anything happening here. (It's an optimization technique.)

Comment: Corrected terminology to one I think reflects correctly the behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually a bit different than that. The parenthesization is as follows

```
[1,2] >>= (\n -> ['a','b'] >>= (\ch -> return (n,ch)))
```

Or, if you prefer

```
let step1 n = 
  let step2 ch = return (n, ch)
  in ['a','b'] >>= step2
in [1,2] >>= step1
```

Comment: Ok. Now I see that the full parenthesization is: `[1,2] >>= ( \n -> ( ['a','b'] >>= \c -> return (n,c) ) )`. But if I try to partially compose it, I think I get: `[1,2] >>= ( \n -> [(n,['a','b'])] )` but that doesn't seems to make sense. Could you post how is the evaluation being carried out? I mean a simple enumeration of the steps that take place.

Comment: The trick is that partial composition like that has to be done by "peeling layers off from the outside". The latter steps in a monadic bind sequence all make sense by themselves, but the former ones do not... at least, not unless you fill the hole with `return`.

Comment: In the second snippet above, the `n` in `step2` is actually unbound.